# GraalVM: Allow external scripts to have access to native compiled objects

Tags: java, groovy, compilation, graalvm

I'm creating a java/groovy application that also supports scripting via groovy. There is a lot of legacy java code and new parts written in Groovy. Beyond that, the app is also scriptable with groovy.

I can keep everything running under the VM and obfuscate symbols from the jars as I did in the past - no problem. BUT:

I'm evaluating using GraalVM to create a native binary, but the question is how will that be compatible with running external groovy scripts during runtime? Does graal retain symbolic information for classes and methods and how is the data exchange for method calls handled from script to native? I'm not sure if this will even work.

From past similar projects, I know that native compilation in most cases, strips the binary of any symbols. I also need this feature in place of obfuscation. The plan is to preserve symbols for some methods and objects that are allowed access by the external groovy scripts only.

Clarification: This relates to GroovyScriptEngine and CroovyClassLoader in particular. sections 1.3 and 1.4 [here](http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html).

How is the memory model of GraalVM compiled groovy compared to the groovy VM?
If I load a class at runtime and pass it an object foo created from the native side, will the script work and be able to use the members as normal or even reflection on foo?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: so you want to build a native image and dynamically load code (the scripts)? That's not supported at the moment afaik.

Comment: To clarify a bit: build a native image but also integrate groovy for scripting [link](http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html).

Comment: @BoriS I've clarified my question to include the relevant groovy docs.

Answer (score 0):

@Boris is correct, groovy uses java classloaders internaly on all script runtime compilation. Without the JVM, the native/Substrate VM version of Graal is unable to run newly generated JVM butecode.